# cannot get simple appendChild function working

Tags: javascript, dom

I am testing javascript code on W3schools' site and I cannot get the appendChild function working.
Hope its not a dumb error.

here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function append()
{
var node = document.getElementById(“history”);
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text"));
}

window.onload = append;
</script>

<div id="history"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have proper double quotes (I don't know what the others are called):

```
document.getElementById(“history”);
//                      ^       ^
```

This throws the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

It works with:

```
document.getElementById("history");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/msxRD/)

---

OT: w3schools is not a good resource for learning (http://w3fools.com/). Better have a look at the Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript

Comment: @user701510: Well, you don't need any tools to detect the error, it is easy to see ;) But to get the error message, I just opened the JavaScript console. Built-in in Chrome and Safari. In Firefox you might want to use Firebug. There are also developer tools for IE.

Comment: @user701510 i think the problem here was that you copied the code from a website where the character codes differ for double quotes and thus you ran into this issue.